# enum defined in Objc > Declared in Swift > to be used in Objc

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, objc-bridging-header

I have a situation. I would appreciated if anyone has a solution for this

- I have an objC `enum` say `Abc`
- I declare this in a swift class, say, `MySwiftClass.swift` as `var abc : Abc!`
- I have created an instance of MySwiftClass (`mySwiftClass`) in another ObjC class (myObjC.m file)
- In myObjC.m, I’m trying to access enum Abc as `mySwiftClass.abc`.

This is throwing an error - “Property ‘abc’ not found on object of type MySwiftClass *”. 
Basically the enum is not added as property in the “ProjectName-Swift.h” file.

What I believe is happening is that when I’m declaring the ObjC enum in Swift class, it is getting converted to a swift enum and hence I’m not able to access it in ObjC file.

**Note:** Marking the Swift class as @objc did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numeric Swift optionals cannot be represented in Objective-C, and thus will not be exposed to Objective-C. Declare `abc` to not be optional and it should be available from Objective-C.

Consider this Objective-C enumeration:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Foo) {
    FooBar,
    FooBaz,
    FooQux
};
```

Then consider this Swift 3 class:

```
class SomeObject: NSObject {
    var foo1: Foo  = .bar          // this is exposed to Objective-C
    var foo2: Foo! = .bar          // this is not
}
```

The non-optional, `foo1`, will be exposed to Objective-C, whereas the optional, `foo2`, will not.